# Not redirect when clicking on tag with href = "#". Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a project in angular, and every time you click on a tag href = "#", it is redirected to the beginning of the project. When you click on a label with a href = "#", do not redirect and nothing happens. I would not want to use event.prevent or something like that, because then I should put this on every HTML tag.
[image]

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="views/login.html">
    <h1>view with my problem</h1>

    this link has href='#'. I need stop redirecting..
    Without using something 'event.prevent' like this because I do not want to do it every time
            <br>

    <a href="#">NOT REDIRECT!</a>
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0hdcb3dr/

I want any part where you find href='#', do not redirect to the default template ($urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')); Should not redirect, but I do not want to use $event.prevent or something like this every time I find myself href ='#'
On a real project I have  href = '#' everywhere, I do not want to fix it one by one.

Comment: Does it have to be an `<a>`? Can't it be a `<button>` ?

Comment: What should that link do then?

Comment: @MatiasCicero https://jsfiddle.net/33ujw8gj/

Comment: @Maccurt https://jsfiddle.net/33ujw8gj/

Comment: @yavg you realize your fiddle is working.. right?

Comment: Can you or someone explain what the specific question is? Because I'm looking at the fiddle, reading the question, but am I the only one not getting what the link should do and should not do?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Just provide an empty `href` attribute:

```
<a href>NOT REDIRECT!</a>
```

I've updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/33ujw8gj/1/) with this change.

Comment: I updated more details... I need made anything where href='#'

Comment: @yavg So if I'm correct, you want a `a href=#` to not do anything? Without any JS preventing it? I do not think this is possible. You must use the method that Matias provided, for it is the only way to achieve what you want.